# I want to write code to read parquet file and store the data in DB table using c#

Tags: .net, database, parquet

I want to write code to read parquet file and store the data  in DB table  using c#

I have parquets files , and also data base tables , for example I want to insert employee parquet data to employee database table using .Net   , How can i achieve this